# How could we pass a list of object between android phone and wear device?

Tags: android, android-wear-data-api

In phone code, I use Serializable to transfer to ByteArray to be passed in an asset, wear(watch) is able to receive it but in the following code, payload doesn't contain any data that can be transferred back to original data.

```
var b = ListToPass(listOf("mission 1", "mission 2"))
this.dataMap.putAsset("KEY", Asset.createFromBytes(b.toByteArray()))

fun Serializable.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val objectOutputStream = ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(this)
    objectOutputStream.flush()
    val result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    byteArrayOutputStream.close()
    objectOutputStream.close()
    return result
  }

  data class ListToPass(
    var test: List<String>
  ) : Serializable
```

wear code to handle the data:

```
val payload = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataEvent.dataItem)
              .dataMap.getAsset(WearViewModel.MISSION_KEY)
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what "can't process it" means. Personally, I would use JSON or some other neutral format, rather than `Serializable`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for replying, I updated accordingly. Do you have any code sample for JSON or other neutral format? I searched online, android developer document or other websites don't mention it.

Comment: JSON has been used for a couple of decades. There is a tremendous amount of material on how to generate and parse JSON in Android apps.

Comment: but no example for passing data between handheld(phone) and wear(watch).